# Get first day of yyyyMM format

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I wish to get the first and the last day of the month with

```
select CONVERT(varchar,dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(m,1,cast(cast('201812' as varchar(6))+'01' as date))),112)
```

Actually I can get the last day of month but I don't know how can I get the first day of month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are starting with '201801`as`yyyymm`, then use:

```
select convert(date, yyyymm + '01') as first_day_of_month,
       eomonth(convert(date, yyyymm + '01')) as last_day_of_month
```